# Gspread quota exceded, error 429 - Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I'm doing a bot to put the result of a website in a sheets with the Google Sheets API. But I received the error 429. I saw some people saying to put a time.sleep to deal with it but I'm not sure where I can put it in my code. Please, could someone help? I'm quite new in Python.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import gspread

scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(r'C:\Users\Camila\Python-projects\avon-chave-sheets.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

result = client.open("Dados_faturados_dia_avon").worksheet("dadosfaturados")

i = 1
while result.cell(i, 1).value != "":
    i = i + 1


result.update_cell(i,1, valores)
```

Error:

```
APIError: {'code': 429, 'message': "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Read requests' and limit 'Read requests per minute per user' of service 'sheets.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:532510513093'.", 'status': 'RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED', 'details': [{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo', 'reason': 'RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED', 'domain': 'googleapis.com', 'metadata': {'quota_limit': 'ReadRequestsPerMinutePerUser', 'consumer': 'projects/532510513093', 'quota_metric': 'sheets.googleapis.com/read_requests', 'service': 'sheets.googleapis.com'}}]}
```

Comment: In your code you need to catch the error to begin probably around result.update_cell if it fails then just try again.

Comment: I have questions for your script. 1. What is `result.update_cell(i,1, valores)`? Is this in the while loop? Or, this is independent on the while loop? 2. What is `valores`? It seems that this is not declared in your script.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you need to catch the error, then retry it.

I am not a python developer but something like this should get you started.

```
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
try:
   result.update_cell(i,1, valores)
except HttpError as err:
  # If the error is a rate limit or connection error,
  # wait and try again.
  if err.resp.status in [403, 429, 500, 503]:
    time.sleep(5)
  else: raise
```

Comment: Hi! @DalmTo thanks so much for answring but I tried here and got the same error :((( Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Im not a python developer your going to have to google around how to catch an error and cause it to run again.   I do this with C# and it works you just need to catch it and retry if it fails.